# A powered hockey suit

Tags: story-identification, tv, armor

I remember a TV movie or mini series from the early 80’s that involved an iron man type of power suit, and I think it was used to play hockey. I don’t think that was the main focus of the show, but that's what I remember.

I think it was set in the end of 1999, but not sure. Also, there was a scene were a kid, doing homework, asks his dad who was president after Reagan, to which his dad answered, “look it up.” Not a great show by any means, just popped into my head and now its bugging the tar out of me that I can't remember or find the name. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Probably [*Generation*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089193/) (1985).

It is from the right time period and features powered armor and hockey.

Could not find the movie, but here is the trailer with the armor.